# Radio button image replacement using :before

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change a label:before background image once the radio button is checked so it swaps the image. I cannot get this to work.

Here is what I have:-

HTML

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-person">
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-radio">
    <span class="wpcf7-list-item first">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="your-person" value="Jobs">&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Jobs</span>
      </label>
    </span>
    <span class="wpcf7-list-item last">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="your-person" value="Employees">&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Employees</span>
      </label>
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

CSS

```
input[type=radio] {
        display:none;
    }

label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 45px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

label:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 1px;
    background: url(../img/unchecked.png);
}

label:checked {
    background: url(../img/checked.png) !important;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Preferably without changing the markup as this comes from Contact Form 7 plugin.

I've made a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rqg3bL27/).

Comment: Hi, you can't use `:checked` on your `label`, try `input:checked + wpcf7-list-item-label` and adjust your styles / background-image placement accordingly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you were getting close, but weren't quite there.

A label can't have `:checked`, this only works for radiobuttons and checkboxes.

You have to modify that it selects a span following an input, like this:

```
input[type=radio] + span:before {
    background-image: url('./unchecked');
}
input[type=radio]:checked + span:before {
    background-image: url('./checked');
}
```

see this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbPbmq) (because codepen is a lot better to check CSS)

Comment: Works absolutely fine, but how is codepen a lot better than JSFiddle? Just wondering how you'd reason that.

Comment: Maybe not a lot, I just dislike JSFiddle for being slow. Codepen loads changes on the spot, has auto indenting, sass and autoprefix.
I prefer [codepen](http://codepen.io/pen) for css, and [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) for javascript.

Comment: JSFiddle has SCSS too, i'd rather not use autoprefixers for showing other people code, there might occur some confusing situations. Why plunkr for javascript? I rarely use it, to me it seems it is fit to test full-blown projects, rather than the snippets that usually occur on SO. But hey, each to his own `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You should try like this -

```css
input[type=radio] {
    display:none;
    opacity:0;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 45px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

label:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 1px;
    background: url(http://46.101.2.132/wp-content/themes/distinct/assets/img/unchecked.png);
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
    content: '';
    background: url(http://46.101.2.132/wp-content/themes/distinct/assets/img/checked.png);
    z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-person">
<span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-radio">
<span class="wpcf7-list-item first">
    <input type="radio" name="your-person" value="Jobs" id="1">
    <label  for="1">&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Jobs</span></label>
</span>
<span class="wpcf7-list-item last">
    <input type="radio" name="your-person" value="Employees" id="2">&nbsp;
    <label for="2">
        <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Employees</span>
    </label>
</span>
</span>
</span>
```

I hope I'll helps you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```css
input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.wpcf7-list-item-label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 45px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.wpcf7-list-item-label:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
  background: url(http://46.101.2.132/wp-content/themes/distinct/assets/img/unchecked.png);
}

input:checked + .wpcf7-list-item-label:before {
  background: url(http://46.101.2.132/wp-content/themes/distinct/assets/img/checked.png) !important;
  //display: none;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-person">
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-radio">
    <span class="wpcf7-list-item first">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="your-person" value="Jobs">&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Jobs
      </span>
    </label>
    </span>
    <span class="wpcf7-list-item last">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="your-person" value="Employees">&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Employees</span>
      </label>
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```